# how to fill open loop polygon in geometry node

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to make a polygon using "curve line" so the polygon is open loop ; then I used "Merge by distance" ; then I wanted to fill the polygon but i couldn't success ; then I saw https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45O51Up5qxw and I made the following picture:
[image]

But I can't understand why there are not overlapped? 
Please help me to get more about this problem . 
In the following you can have the blender file: [image]

And  in this file you can find my polygon file: [image]

Comment: If you want to copy the vertices position, you must link the *Attribute* socket of the *Transfer Attribute* node to the *Position* socket of the *Set Position* node, not to the *Offset* socket.